# Does the "PlatformRollbackMethod" Windows Defender event indicate an issue?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, event-log, windows-defender, event-viewer

For about a month I've been seeing this "PlatformRollbackMethod" in event viewer (Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational)
Is this a common event, or an unusual one that might indicate a problem?

> Microsoft Defender Antivirus Configuration has changed. If this is an
> unexpected event you should review the settings as this may be the
> result of malware.
>
> Old value: Default\Diagnostics\PlatformRollbackMethod = 0x0
>
> New value: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
> Defender\Diagnostics\PlatformRollbackMethod = 0x3
>
> Source: Windows Defender.
>
> Event ID 5007
>
> User: System
>
> Information

The OS is Windows 10 21h2

Thanks

**Edited 6th Jan 2022** with aditional information below:-

There have been different additional events with the 5007 Event ID, Since 27th December '21.
These include text like this:

```
Old value: Default\Diagnostics\RolledbackPlatformHealthData = 0

New value: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Diagnostics\
RolledbackPlatformHealthData = <OVERALL>:<BAD>,<AGE>:<19>,<DIRTY_SHUTDOWNS>:<7>
```

Events with text similar to this have happened 9 times since 27th Dec.

Sometimes the entries for the New / Old value are the other way round.

The "Dirty Shutdowns" number doesn't correspond to the number of PC unexpected shutdowns.

I'm avoiding if possible doing a repair of the install as it takes a long time to change all the settings and preferences.

Comment: Did you try updating Defender?  Defender window ,  Virus and Threat. Scroll down the right side for Virus and Threat Protection and click on Updates. Run updates to get Defender and Antimalware updated

Comment: Thanks, yes I often update Defender. I see engine updates in the same log as above. The PlatformRollbackMethod entries are not always around the same time as an update. The PlatformRollbackMethod events are often shortly after startup, sometimes the values are swapped around.

Comment: I am not seeing this issue in Windows 10 or 11. You may wish to consider a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link and use the option to Keep Everything.